# Uploaded image: converting format

Tags: php, image, imagemagick

I want to convert a uploaded image to its original format, (jpg, jpeg rpng, etc.) but I need to re-size these images to be 150px width and 210px height. Is it possible to change the size while copying, or do I have to convert it?

This was unsucessful:

```
    $uploaddir1 = "/home/myweb/public_html/temp/sfds454.png";
    $uploaddir2 = "/home/myweb/public_html/images/sfds454.png";

    $cmd = "/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i $uploaddir1 -vframes 1 -s 150x210 -r 1 -f mjpeg $uploaddir2";
    @exec($cmd);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had to solve just this problem, and implemented this simple caching solution:

```
<?php
function send($name, $ext) {
    $fp = fopen($name, 'rb');
    // send the right headers
    header("Content-Type: image/$ext");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));

    // dump the picture and stop the script
    fpassthru($fp);
    exit;
}

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

if (isset($_REQUEST['fp'])) {
    $ext = pathinfo($_REQUEST['fp'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $allowedExt = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg');
    if (!in_array($ext, $allowedExt)) {
        echo 'fail';
    }

    if (!isset($_REQUEST['w']) && !isset($_REQUEST['h'])) {
        send($_REQUEST['fp']);
    }
    else {
        $w = $_REQUEST['w'];
        $h = $_REQUEST['h'];

        //use height, width, modification time and path to generate a hash
        //that will become the file name
        $filePath = realpath($_REQUEST['fp']);
        $cachePath = md5($filePath.filemtime($filePath).$h.$w);
        if (!file_exists("tmp/$cachePath")) {
            exec("gm convert -quality 80% -colorspace RGB -resize " .$w .'x' . $h . " $filePath tmp/$cachePath");
        }
        send("tmp/$cachePath", $ext);

    }
}
?>
```

Some things that I noticed:

1. Graphicsmagick converted much faster than imagemagick, although I did not test conversion with cuda processing.
2. For the final product I re-implemented this code in ASP using the language's native graphics library. This was much faster again but would break if out-of-memory errors occurred (worked fine on my workstation, but wouldn't work on 4GB RAM server).

Answer (score 3):

You can use **gd** instead of **ffmpeg**. To convert or resize an image, see this example: http://ryanfait.com/resources/php-image-resize/resize.txt

Php lib for **gd**:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php

There is also some samples of resizing scripts in that page.